# Cannot connect to websocket from website using Nodejs within browser

Tags: node.js, websocket, chat

Has anybody had luck creating a website with real-time communication (chat) using Nodejs and websockets on Fastcomet?  I've submitted many tickets to Fastcomet but we keep going in circles.

My goal is to put something like https://davidwalsh.name/websocket online at www.mywebsite.com/socketio

All my tests work locally when I open http://127.0.0.1:3000/ in my browser.

I started by setting up a [Node.js app from cpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFJxt.jpg)

then [fill in the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejl0y.jpg)

This procedure creates a .htaccess file for Phusion Passenger.

*even tried RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:3000/$1 [P]*

When I go to www.mywebsite.com/socketio I get the following error:

*http://www.mywebsite:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1531226905601-0
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED*

Here is another failed test:

Server index.js (Nodejs status: started)

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   var message = 'It works!\n',
       version = 'NodeJS ' + process.versions.node + '\n',
       response = [message, version].join('\n');
   res.end(response);
});
server.listen();
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
 ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
  console.log('received: %s', message);
 });
 ws.send('something')
});
```

client index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var sock =new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host+"/chat" );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

even tried

```
var sock =new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host+":8080/chat" );
```

I also changed port 8080 to 3000 for the index.js and index.html

I even removed port from index.js and index.html

Access through browser at:

**http://www.mywebsite.com/chat/index.html**

Error:

*WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.mywebsite.com/chat' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500*

Anybody have ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED might indicate that the DNS isn't setup properly or that the domain can't be reached for some reason. Are you able to access your domain normally by just going to http://www.mywebsite.com? And have you tried not entering the www and only the domain part?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating your project outside the public_html folder?

Try creating a folder (eg: home/user/socket_test) and put your code inside that folder and point your node.js app to that path.

Ports are mapped automatically in "Phusion Passenger" meaning whatever port you specify in the program will be automatically reverse mapped by phusion passenger.

Use port 3000 for node apps, example.com/app will have port of 8080 getting mapped to port 3000.

I'm using Fastcommet shared hosting plan and running a node express RESTful API and its working very well.

Comment: Can you please give more information regarding your setup?  here is my setup. Application root: home/user/socket_test.
Application URL: [mydomain]/wschat.
Application startup file: index.js.

index.html: new WebSocket("wss://[mydomain]:3000/wschat").

error: WebSocket connection to 'wss://[mydomain]:3000/wschat' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: Can you please give more info on how you got it to work?